# Jquery script not working on page where form is send to

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a php file with a form. The form action is to another php file.
When I submit the form, the Jquery on the next page (the form action page) is not working. But when i open that page by myself (not by the form action) the Jquery is working perfect.

Code on first page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" id="status">
      <h1>Snacks Bestellen</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="evaluatelogin.php">
      <label for="company">Bedrijfsnummer:</label>
      <input type="text" name="company" id="company">
      <fieldset class="ui-field-contain" id="fieldset_user">
        <label for="user">Gebruiker:</label>
        <select name="user" id="user">
        </select>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" value="Volgende" data-icon="user" data-iconpos="right" data-inline="true">
      </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Code on the evaluatelogin.php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="getsnacks.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" id="status">
      <h1>Snacks Bestellen</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

        <fieldset class="ui-field-contain" id="snack1">
            <span id="snack1optie1">
            <select name="optie1" id="optie1" class="optie1">
            </select>
            </span>
            <span id="snack1optie2">
            <select name="optie2" id="optie2" class="optie2">
            </select>
            </span>
            <span id="snack1optie3">
            <select name="optie3" id="optie3" class="optie3">
            </select>
            </span>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Jquery on the page (just a test):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#snack1optie2').hide();
    $('#snack1optie3').hide();      
    $('#snack1optie1').click(function(){
        $('#snack1optie2').show();
    });
    $('#snack1optie2').click(function(){
        $('#snack1optie3').show();
    });
    $('#snack1optie3').click(function(){
        $('#snack1optie3').hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: where are you placing your Jquery code?

Comment: It is in the getsnacks.js file in the HEAD.

Comment: try to write your code outside $(document).ready

Comment: Place `getsnacks.js` in the end of the body tag and then test it @MelisDekker

Comment: That is also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form submit is performed with AJAX.

> On submit, jQuery Mobile will make sure that the Url specified is able to be retrieved via Ajax, and handle it appropriately.

Disabled it with `data-ajax="false"` form attribute and it will work fine.

```
<form method="post" action="evaluatelogin.php" data-ajax="false">
```

[jQuery mobile docs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html)